Re-write a zsh_lf snippet to work in zellij instead of tmux
I am trying to rewrite the code below (source):
_zlf() {
    emulate -L zsh
    local d=$(mktemp -d) || return 1
    {
        mkfifo -m 600 $d/fifo || return 1
        tmux split -bf zsh -c "exec {ZLE_FIFO}>$d/fifo; export ZLE_FIFO; exec lf" || return 1
        local fd
        exec {fd}<$d/fifo
        zle -Fw $fd _zlf_handler
    } always {
        rm -rf $d
    }
}
zle -N _zlf
bindkey '\ek' _zlf

_zlf_handler() {
    emulate -L zsh
    local line
    if ! read -r line <&$1; then
        zle -F $1
        exec {1}<&-
        return 1
    fi
    eval $line
    zle -R
}
zle -N _zlf_handler

I am using zellij rather than tmux
Can someone help me to rewrite this?
I tried simply replacing the tmux line with this:
zellij run --floating -- "zsh -c 'exec {ZLE_FIFO}>$d/fifo; export ZLE_FIFO; exec lf'" || return 1

but I am getting
command not found: "zsh -c 'exec {ZLE_FIFO}>$d/fifo; export ZLE_FIFO; exec lf'" if you were including arguments as part of the command, try including them as 'args' instead.

Any idea what is the correct way of re-writing this? I am only a beginner, so I appreciate if someone provide me with the re-write and a brief explanation so that i can troubleshoot in the future.
Thanks in advance.

What worked for me is the below:
I replaced the tmux line with
zellij run --floating -- zsh -c "exec {ZLE_FIFO}>$d/fifo; export ZLE_FIFO; exec lf" || return 1

Thanks to @steeldriver for pointing out about the double quotes.
